# Unable to strip and store content of some files in CSV format

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I have a files which have look like:

They are placed in

```
~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_1/inventory/group_vars/all 
~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_2/inventory/group_vars/all
~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_3/inventory/group_vars/all
```

I wrote:

```
    import os
import sys
rootdir='/home/USER/ansible-environments/aws'
#print "aa"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdir in subdirs:
        all_path = os.path.join(rootdir, subdir, "inventory", "group_vars", "all")
        if not os.path.isfile(all_path):
            continue
        try:
            with open(all_path, "r") as f:
                all_content = f.readlines()
        except (OSError, IOError):
            continue  # ignore errors
        csv_line = [""] * 3
        for line in all_content:
            if line[:9] == "isv_alias:":
                csv_line[0] = line[7:].strip()
            elif line[:21] == "LMID:":
                csv_line[1] = line[6:].strip()
            elif line[:17] == "products:":
                csv_line[2] = line[10:].strip()
        if all(value != "" for value in csv_line):
            with open(os.path.join("/home/nsingh/nishlist.csv"), "a") as csv:
                csv.write(",".join(csv_line))
                csv.write("\n")
```

I just need the LMIT, isv_alias, products in the following format :

```
alias,LMIT,product
bloodyhell,80,rms_scl
something_else,434,some_other_prod
```

Comment: Question is unclear. You have no isv_alias in your file, for example

Comment: Your approach seems to be off. You need to extract values values after the colon character. You are simply filtering the lines. Look into the `re` module.

Comment: Are all the files directly inside `~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_1/inventory/group_vars/all`, or are they in subdirectories of that directory?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan yes, you are right i need to find jsut the `value`

Comment: @DamianYerrick updated the question, there are many `~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_1/inventory/group_var‌​s/all` ,
`~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_2/inventory/group_var‌​s/all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems here:

1. Finding all key-value files
2. Extracting keys and values from each file
3. Turning the keys and values from each file into rows in a CSV

First use `os.listdir()` to find the contents of
`~/ansible-environments/aws`, then build the expected path of the
`inventory/group_vars` directory inside each using
`os.path.join()`, and see which ones actually exist.  Then list
the contents of those directories that do exist, and assume all
files inside (such as `all`) are key-value files.  The example
code at the end of this answer assumes that all files can be
found this way; if they cannot, you may have to adapt the example
code to find the files using `os.walk()` or another method.

Each key-value file is a sequence of lines, where each line is a key
and value separated by a colon (`":"`).  Your approach using search
for a substring (operator `in`) will fail if, say, the secret key
contains the string "LMIT".  Instead, split the line at the colon.
The expression `line.split(":", 1)` splits the line at the first
colon, but not subsequent colons in case the value itself has a
colon.  Then strip off excess whitespace from the key and value,
and build a dictionary of keys and values.

Now choose which keys you want to keep.  Once you've parsed each
file, look up the associated values in the dictionary from that
file, and build a list out of them.  Then add the list of values
from this file to a list of lists of values from all files, and
use `csv.writer` to write out the list of lists as a CSV file.

It might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import with_statement, print_function, division
import os
import csv

def read_kv_file(filename):
    items = {}
    with open(filename, "rU") as infp:
        for line in infp:
            # Split at a colon and strip leading and trailing space
            line = [x.strip() for x in line.split(":", 1)]

            # Add the key and value to the dictionary
            if len(line) > 1:
                items[line[0]] = line[1]
    return items

# First find all random names
outer_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/ansible-environments/aws")
random_names = os.listdir(outer_dir)
inner_dirs = [
    os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars")
    for name in random_names
]

# Now filter it to those directories that actually exist
inner_dirs = [name for name in inner_dirs if os.path.isdir(name)]

wanted_keys = ["alias", "LMIT", "products"]
out_columns = ["alias", "LMIT", "product"]

# Collect key-value pairs from all files in these folders
rows = []
for dirname in inner_dirs:
    for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)

        # Skip non-files in this directory
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            continue

        # If the file has a non-blank value for any of the keys of
        # interest, add a row
        items = read_kv_file(path)
        this_file_values = [items.get(key) for key in wanted_keys]
        if any(this_file_values):
            rows.append(this_file_values)

# And write them out
with open("out.csv", "wb") as outfp:
    writer = csv.writer(outfp, "excel")
    writer.writerow(out_columns)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: its just printing "alias", "LMIT", "product" in csv file , also the folder "~/ansible-environments/aws" it might contain a directory which might not have a subfolder with inventory

Comment: Which one of the three steps are you having trouble with? Finding the files, parsing them, or writing the result? You could adapt my code to use `os.walk` and/or `print` the results of intermediate substeps in step 1. Without access to a system matching yours, I cannot test code for step 1.

Comment: there is a folder inside '~/ansible-environments/aws/' which doesn't contain the same structure , i will paste the code in pastebin for u to see

Comment: If the files do not in fact follow the directory structure that you had outlined in comments, then you could try adapting my code to find the key-value files inside the "folder inside '~/ansible-environments/aws/' which doesn't contain the same structure" with `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`. Or can you not figure out how to adapt my code to use `os.walk`?

Comment: this part is not clear to me 

``inner_dirs = [
    os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars/all")

    for name in random_names
]
` 

i am not sure how can i get inside the subdirectory

Comment: What is the value of `inner_dirs`? If you do not know, please modify the program to print the value of `inner_dirs`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135920/discussion-between-kittystone-and-damian-yerrick).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how are you obtaining the files (the `f` in the first line) but under the assumption that you've sorted out the files traversal and that the files are exactly as you present them (so no extra spaces or something like that), you can modify your code to:

```
csv_line = [""] * 3
for line in f:
    if line[:6] == "alias:":
        csv_line[0] = line[7:].strip()
    elif line[:5] == "LMIT:":
        csv_line[1] = line[6:].strip()
    elif line[:9] == "products:":
        csv_line[2] = line[10:].strip()
with open(rootdir + '/' + 'list.csv', "a") as csv:
    csv.write(",".join(csv_line))
    csv.write("\n")
```

This will add a new line with the proper vars in your CSV for each file that was loaded as `f`, however keep in mind that it doesn't check for the data validity so it will be happy to write empty new lines if the opened file didn't contain the proper data.

You can prevent that by checking for `all(value != "" for value in csv_line)`  before opening the csv file for writing. You can use `any` instead of `all` if you want to write entries that have at least one variable populated.

**UPDATE:** The code you just pasted has serious indentation and structural issues. It at least make more sense on what you want to do - assuming everything else is ok, this should do it:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdir in subdirs:
        all_path = os.path.join(rootdir, subdir, "inventory", "group_vars", "all")
        if not os.path.isfile(all_path):
            continue
        try:
            with open(all_path, "r") as f:
                all_content = f.readlines()
        except (OSError, IOError):
            continue  # ignore errors
        csv_line = [""] * 3
        for line in all_content:
            if line[:6] == "alias:":
                csv_line[0] = line[7:].strip()
            elif line[:5] == "LMIT:":
                csv_line[1] = line[6:].strip()
            elif line[:9] == "products:":
                csv_line[2] = line[10:].strip()
        if all(value != "" for value in csv_line):
            with open(os.path.join(rootdir, "list.csv"), "a") as csv:
                csv.write(",".join(csv_line))
                csv.write("\n")
```

Comment: Makes more sense now, see the update above. Still, thing like this could use a bit more structure and flexibility, but this should at least give you the idea on how to do it....

Comment: whats the meaning of csv_line = [""] * 3

Comment: Just initializing the list with three empty strings to be filled in later when a value is found. You can also write it as `csv_line = ["", "", ""]`

Comment: zwer, i am unable to extract ,, i have updated the code as follows a